# Компиляция из исходников и установка из пакетов в чем разница?

Tags: linux, компиляция, установка

Нередко читаю комментарии в интернете, что компиляция и установка приложений из исходников лучше (по быстродействию приложения), чем установка из пакетов.

Подскажите пожалуйста в чем разница? (в качестве примера можно взять установка nginx на голой Ubuntu 16.04)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Установка с пакета обычно подразумевает, что Вам предоставляют готовое скомпилированное приложение (но это не обязательно так, бывает по-всякому). А значит, что будет собрано ровно то, что решил автор пакета. А это может не подходить для конкретного случая.

Когда код собирается вручную, то можно поотключать часть функционала, а часть включить. Это может дать некий прирост производительности. А может и наоборот. Можно включить экспериментальную функциональность, а можно выключить ту, в которой нашли уязвимость. А можно заплату быстро накатить. Это все требует хорошего знания продукта и системы сборки. К тому же сборка вручную пакета на системах с готовыми пакетами сопряжена с разными проблемами - например, при обновлении может перетереть самособранный пакет (все можно настроить, но ...).

Возвращаясь к nginx. В нем часть модулей часто не идет "из коробки" (то есть, не включены в пакет). Это обычно редкие модули, но иногда они бывают нужны. Я встречал, к примеру, что распаковка тела запроса, зажатого gzip, по умолчанию не включена, и пришлось учить пхп распаковывать.

Почему же гуляет этот миф? Просто раньше, да и сейчас почему-то считается, что дистрибутивы типа gentoo очень сложны, но с другой стороны суперпроизводительны (надо же как-то оправдать постоянные пересборки мира). А если они сложны, значит, должны хорошо работать (если, конечно, их правильно настроить). По факту, получить плюс можно, но только для ядра и некоторых пакетов (например, vlc или ffmpeg).

**Выводы:**

- нужна ли Вам пересборка nginx на убунте? Вряд ли. Маловероятно, что Вы получите какой-то прирост производительности.
- а если сильно хочется пересобирать? разверните тестовую систему и пробуйте. Делайте бенчмарки. А ещё хорошо взять дистрибутив, который это поддерживает из коробки - gentoo, funtoo, LFS.

Comment: Большое спасибо за разъяснение!

Answer (score 5):

#### плюсы

1. вы научитесь выполнять команду

   ```
   $ make && sudo make install
   ```

   или что-нибудь подобное (в зависимости от того, как задуман процесс сборки/установки разработчиком программы).
2. осознаете, что если в вашем дистрибутиве используется пакетный менеджер, то при очередном обновлении пакетов процесс может застопориться из-за конфликтов с теми файлами/каталогами, которые щедро разбросала по файловой системе процедура «установки», реализованная разработчиками этой программы (которые вряд ли заморачивались необходимостью «вписываться» в требования политик всех существующих на свете дистрибутивов).
3. узнаете, что не все разработчики предусматривают средства удаления всех разбрасываемых в процессе «установки» по файловой системе файлов/каталогов.
4. научитесь вручную находить и удалять все эти артефакты, и править сборочные скрипты на предмет избежания подобных конфликтов в будущем.
5. задумаетесь: а не лучше ли было всего лишь пересобрать существующий пакет, подложив в него новую версию исходников, и подправив нужные для вас опции сборки.
6. научитесь собирать пакеты для вашего дистрибутива.
7. узнаете, что пересобранный и установленный вами в систему пакет может быть перезаписан дистрибутивным при очередном обновлении пакетов.
8. воспользуетесь средствами пакетного менеджера, препятствующими такому перезаписыванию.
9. научитесь автоматизировать процесс пересборки вашего пакета после выхода очередной версии программы.

и т.д. и т.п.

#### минусы

да, практически, и нет, с такими-то плюсами.

Comment: Может лучше всё-таки `checkinstall`? Иронию я распарсил.

Comment: @donRumata, сути, с моей точки зрения, это не меняет. но вообще-то я вёл к примерно такому финалу: «станете мэйнтэйнером пакета и перестанете ощущать разницу между "самосборкой" и "из репозитория"». но решил не усложнять.